# How to commentize a word in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to **commentize a word under the cursor** and use it as a macro or map it as a key binding.

For example this:

```
void somefunc(MyType* pType);
```

Would become:

```
void somefunc(MyType* /*pType*/);
```

I know that I just need to prepend and append word with /* and */ but I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try either of this mapping, pick one you feel better.

```
nnoremap <leader>cw caw/*<c-o>P*/<esc>
```

or

```
nnoremap <leader>cw viw<esc>a*/<esc>hbi/*<esc>
```

type `<leader>cw` in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

A way more general way to create inline comments is to use [the Tcomment plugin](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim).

When you've installed it you can use the `gc` operator to comment something, for example if you have the following file (with `^` indicating the cursor):

```
void somefunc(MyType* ^pType);
```

Pressing `gce` will get you:

```
void somefunc(MyType* /*pType*/);
```

You can use this for any motion command, but of course a line wise operator (eg. `gcj`) will not comment inline but entire lines instead.